# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager does not release connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Spring to achieve the following:

On a server, I receive data via a REST interface in an XML-Format. I want to transform the data into JSON and POST it to another Server. My code (I removed some sensitive classnames/URLs to avoid the wrath of my employer) looks like this:

Main/Configuration class:

```
package stateservice;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start!");
        SpringApplication.run(StateServiceApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("End!");
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        log.trace("restTemplate()");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy_url", 8080);
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        // Increase max total connection to 200
        cm.setMaxTotal(200);
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();

        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(cm);
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClientBuilder.build());
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
}
```

The class representing the RESTful interface:

```
package stateservice;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import foo.bar.XmlData

@RestController
public class StateController {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataController.class);

    @Autowired
    ForwarderService forwarder;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postState(@RequestBody XmlData data) {
        forwarder.forward(data);
        return "Done!";
    }
}
```

Finally, the Forwarder:

```
package stateservice;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import foo.bar.Converter;
import foo.bar.XmlData;

@Service
public class ForwarderService {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ForwarderService.class);

    String uri = "forward_uri";

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Async
    public String forward(XmlData data) {
        log.trace("forward(...) - start");
        String json = Converter.convert(data);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri,
                new HttpEntity<String>(json, headers), String.class);
        // responseEntity.getBody();
        // log.trace(responseEntity.toString());
        log.trace("forward(...) - end");
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

However, the Connection Manager seldomly seems to release connections for reuse, and additionally, the system gets flooded with connections in the CLOSE_WAIT state (which can be seen using netstat). All connections in the pool get leased, but not released, and as soon as the number of connections in the CLOSE_WAIT state reaches the ulimit, I get 'Too many open files'-exceptions

Because of the multithreaded nature of the code, I suspect that sockets cannot be closed/connections be released, because some other thread is somhow blocking them.

I would really appreciate any help or any hint you can give me to solve the problem.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Are you sure that the server is delivering responses? have you tried setting the `setConnectTimeout` and `setReadTimeout` properties in the `requestFactory`? Does it work when you call the `ForwardedService` synchronously (without the `@Async`)?

Comment: Yes, the server responds (Status '200 OK'). I set the timeouts and called the forwarding-method synchronously - nothing helped.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to configure a KeepAlive strategy. Have a look at chapter 2.6 in the [http client docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

Comment: From the code, it is not clear that connection is getting released to the pool after the use. Make sure that you are calling below API in **try{}catch{} block** once when are you release the connection to the pool.
    releaseConnection

Comment: What versions of Spring Web and HttpClient do you use?

Comment: Since you're using RestTemplate, I'm pretty confident that connections are being handled correctly. I've never had problems with it. Of course, you could check your Spring version for updates. Another thing to try is not using the proxy.

Answer (score 8):

There is a trick with Apache HttpEntity - to release locked connection - response has to be FULLY **consumed** and **closed**. See [EntityUtils](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) and [HttpEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) docs for details:

```
EntityUtils.consume(response);
```

Since version 4.3 Apache HttpClient releases connection back to the pool when #close() method is called on the CloseableHttpResponse.

However this feature is supported by Spring Web only since version 4.0.0-RELEASE, see method #close() in [HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse.java/):

```
@Override
public void close() {
    // Release underlying connection back to the connection manager
    try {
        try {
            // Attempt to keep connection alive by consuming its remaining content
            EntityUtils.consume(this.httpResponse.getEntity());
        } finally {
            // Paranoia
            this.httpResponse.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ignore) {
    }
}
```

The key to success is the line marked by "// Paranoia" - explicit .close() call. It actually releases connection back to pool.

Comment: Does this also work with `try-with-resources` pattern?